# NavigationDrawer Menu Item selected by position

Tags: android, onclicklistener, menuitem, navigation-drawer

I have got NavigationDrawer divided into two sections. First contains menu items with ID's such as "back",  "exit" and so on. It is created using xml file. Second one is being created dynamically, so I can't figure out any kind of ID or something. And because it is a menu-kind object, I can't figure out a way to write a proper listener to items from second section. For example: If I click item 1 from section 2, activity 1 starts, etc. Any ideas? Fragment of my code:

Creating second section of my NavigationDrawer' Menu

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onActivityResult", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

                arrayFav.clear();
                arrayLin.clear();
                ArrayList<String> passedText = data.getStringArrayListExtra("text");
                ArrayList<String> passedLink = data.getStringArrayListExtra("link");

                arrayFav.addAll(passedText);
                arrayLin.addAll(passedLink);

                NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
                Menu mainMenu = navigationView.getMenu();

                final Menu menuWithFavJobs = mainMenu.addSubMenu(Fav jobs: "+mEditTextPraca.getText().toString());

                for (int i = 0; i < arrayFav.size(); i++) {
                    menuWithFavJobs.add(arrayFav.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and the part where I used first' sections ID's to make some actions:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_back) {}
        else if (id == R.id.nav_export) {
            onExportPressed();
        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_exit) {
            onExitPressed();
        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

I tried:

```
menuWithFavJobs.getItem(i).setOnMenuItemClickListener()...
```

but it works only for menu with one item :(
Please for any hints! :) I've got to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for loop, which adds items to your submenu. You need to save the return value of `menuWithFavJobs.add()`. It returns a `MenuItem` object. Then you can call:

```
MenuItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener()
```

Just created this and tried it:

```
Menu mainMenu = navigationView.getMenu();
mainMenu.add("Test OUTER");
Menu subMenu = mainMenu.addSubMenu("SubMenu");

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    MenuItem item = subMenu.add("Submenu Item " + i);

    final int count = i;
    item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "THIS IS A TEST" + count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Tested, works good. The problem must arise somewhere else in your code?

Comment: Yeah! The solution was really simply. But that proves coding isn't the best idea in the middle of the night :) Thanks!